# Unable to plot using plotly. (Python For Finance Cookbook)

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, finance

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import iplot, init_notebook_mode

df = yf.download('SPY',start='2019-01-01', end = '2020-04-20')

init_notebook_mode()
qf = cf.QuantFig(df, title='SPY Price', legend='top', name='SPY')
qf.add_volume()
qf.add_sma(periods=20, column='Close', color='red')
qf.add_ema(periods=20, color='green')

qf.iplot()
```

Error i receive: PlotlyRequestError: Authentication credentials were not provided.

Comment: Try to minimize code example to reproduce this error. Looks like Plotly API requires some credentials

Answer (score 1):

I've written a finance plotting library which can do what you're looking for:

```
import yfinance as yf
import finplot as fplt

df = yf.download('SPY',start='2019-01-01', end = '2020-04-20')

fplt.create_plot('SPY Price')
fplt.candlestick_ochl(df[['Open','Close','High','Low']])
fplt.plot(df.Close.rolling(20).mean(), color='#f00')
fplt.plot(df.Close.ewm(span=20).mean(), color='#0f0')
fplt.show()
```

It's optimized and I frequently use it to plot half a million or more candle sticks. Good luck!

Comment: Just stumbled across this. Does it work in Jupyter notebook? Nothing's happening when I run your script above. I noticed on the github page you mention "It does not work with Jupyter Labs" ... does this mean jupyter notebook too?

Comment: @SCool: Yes, it has no web support.